# Sqlite connection string options in java

Tags: java, sqlite

net developer and pretty new to Java. In .net we add the following options to the connection string so that the journal is not created each time when the database operation is performed.

```
default isolation level=RepeatableRead;synchronous=Full;pooling=True;journal mode=Persist;
```

how to do it in java. i tried with properties

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
prop.put("default isolation level", "RepeatableRead");
prop.put("synchronous","Full");
prop.put("pooling","True");
prop.put("journal mode","Persist");
```

and used with `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + ClientDBPath, prop);`

but it does seems to work. My problem is we have java udp client which will insert /update the database continuously when it receives data from the server. During this process when the UI flex application tries to access it could not execute the query. so we created a sample applications (one for reading and another for writing) and checked in .net with  above connection string options. It worked normally. so trying the same in java.

Please also advise the other options to resolve this insert/ reading issue. Sorry if i have explained much.

Comment: Look into Connection Pooling alternatives like BoneCP or C3P0. You can't do it directly with a Driver and with properties.

Comment: Isolation levels can be modified in the connection object itself: `conn.setTransactionIsolation(Conn.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);`